# Open-source Java-based framework that has many of the common features built in out-of-the-box?

Tags: java, drupal, content-management-system

I am looking for something like Drupal in Java -- not Drupal as a CMS but rather as an application programming framework.

For example I would like to get out the the box:

1. A Login screen
2. The ability to define new roles
3. The ability to tie permissions (capabilities) to roles
4. The ability to assign roles to specific users (and revoke roles)
5. The ability to self-service passwords (reset ones own password)
6. An ability to generate a CRUD app
7. A menu system (that allows you to define menus)

My understanding is that Ruby-on-Rails provides this type of stuff.

Thanks.

Comment: You are wrong about Rails itself, it is a framework for building these kinds of things but it does not provide them out of the box. And It has little to do with Java.

Comment: If you like RoR and Java just use JRuby with Warbler (Rails servlet integration).

Comment: Know little of RoR -- but you are correct I'm looking for a framework which out of the box (or with the use of plug-ins) let's me build a decent application -- I guess liferay/dotCMS or possibly the-play-framework as some of the other respondents have cited may fit the bill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is for Web development, go take a look at the Play! framework.

http://www.playframework.org/

Comment: Additionally, have a look at this Play! CMS: https://bitbucket.org/psartini/percont/. I assume it handles things like passwords and sessions and has some of the other things you requested.

Comment: Good suggestions on Playframework - but from a quick glance it does seem to support the CRUD side of the house but not the other stuff.

Comment: on  bitbucket.org/psartini/percont -- very interesting but it seems a bit embryonic at this time.

Comment: @memmakers Other stuff? Login screen. Yes. Menu system. Yes. And to other things are probably available because there's a module system in Play!. You can install modules that will add features to the framework.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/).

It has all you mentioned and a powerful built-in CMS, user management, lots of out-of-the box "applications" (portlets) to add to your pages, lots of themes to choose from, menus and all.

Basically, you can build a complete dynamic site with all the basic functionalities without writing one line of Java code (or any kind of code).

Comment: I looked @ liferay and dotcms -- I was confused as dotcms bundles liferay with it?

Comment: Don't know much about dotcms... aparently it's been built on LR and then forked out. It doesn't seem to support JSR-286 (Portlet 2.0) though, which you may find a major drawback.

Comment: It seems liferay has "custom attributes" ... how diverse can these be? can be refer other objects, be images, embedded media types, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You might also look into Backbase http://www.backbase.com/

I have no experience with it, but it's all the rage at my wifes company.

Comment: Hi -- I ran into this a while back but I think this is closed source.

Answer (score 0):

try [openxava](http://www.openxava.org/web/guest/home) too

> "OpenXava is a tool for Rapid Java Web Development, well-suited for business and database oriented applications"

Comment: mmm ... The english site does not seem to be very english :-(